# How to linearly scale an integer into 100 parts, even if it is below 100?

Tags: rust

How can I split a single integer into 100 parts?

The max value and last value will be the input value.

The code is what I have come up with so far:

```
fn main() {
    let max_value: i32 = 6543;
    let part = max_value.checked_div(100).unwrap();

    for no in 1..=100 {
        let num = if no == 100 { max_value } else { part * no };
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}
```

This works well if `max_value` is 100 or larger:

```
65
130
195
260
325
390
455
[…]
6240
6305
6370
6435
6543
```

But for `max_value` smaller than 100 it doesn't work at all:

```
    let max_value: i32 = 90;
```

```
0
0
0
0
[…]
0
0
0
0
90
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Is runtime an issue? Should it be accurate? If you have a maximum of 199, part would be 1, the 99th value is 99, the 100th is 199. To do it better either you can do a new division in each loop iteration or add up the remainders, too and test, when to go up or down. Read up about Bresenham's line algorithm and set deltax between the points to 101 and deltay to your max value. The 101 would include the 0 as first element.

Comment: @Sebastian runtime should be fast and doesn't need to be accurate except the last value must be the input value.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am calculating 1-100% of the input value. So vec[0] should equal 1% of the input value and vec[99] should equal 100% of the input value.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's error-prone. For example, if the max_value is < 100

Comment: Any particular reason why you avoid floating-point arithmetic? If you have one, can you write it in the question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Why did you totally change the question? In the original post, the case *below 100* was just a corner-case since huge values seemed to be the main concern, but now it's the main purpose of the question.

Comment: Because for all other cases there was no problem. And I didn't know how to compile the code with non-standard types used, i.e. it wasn't a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with the following characteristics:

- Pure integer arithmetic.
- No overflow as long as the divisor `d` is less than `2 * u32::MAX` (or the max of whatever integer type you are using).
- O(1) integer divisions.
- Steps are as evenly spaced as possible – the result is the same as using `n * i / d` for `i` in `1..=d`, but with only integer additions in each loop iteration, and without the problems with integer overflow.

```
fn divide_integer(n: u32, d: u32) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> {
    let step = n / d;
    let rem_step = n % d;
    (0..d).scan((0, 0), move |(current, rem), _| {
        *current += step;
        *rem += rem_step;
        if *rem >= d {
            *rem -= d;
            *current += 1;
        }
        Some(*current)
    })
}
```

This increases the current value `current` by `n / d` in each iteration, but also keeps track of the remainder `rem`. The increment for the remainder `rem_step` is always less than `d`, so `rem` will always be less than `2 * d`, so `rem` cannot overflow if `d <= u32::MAX`. The value of `current` is less than or equal to `n` at all times, so `current` can never overflow.

Comment: For future reference and less advanced programmers: the basic algorithm was IMHO easier to understand in [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71615282/1) of this answer.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It felt wrong to allocate a vector if we don't need to. I guess you are completely right that some people will find the first version easier to understand.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for your help. Can this be used with U256 integers?

Comment: @James Sure – you just need to use `U256::zero()` and `U256::one()` where approriate.

Comment: If you want to parallelize this algorithm (with suitable architectures), you can calculate in-between results, e.g. `current` and `rem` at the 25th, 50th, 75th element _or_ for the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th element and adapt the `step`and `rem_step` for a jump by 4.

Comment: @Sebastian sounds interesting. Thanks for your input. Is that something I can do with rayon? Is any example code out of the scope of this SO question?

Comment: @James I am not so versed in Rust (but other languages); by the looks of it, it should be possible with rayon. Perhaps somebody could step in / help?